# matching date format as string in python doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have 2 functions as part of a bigger program, which I wanted to highlight below:

```
def compare_date(date1,date2):
    date_tm_obj_url = datetime.strptime(date1, check_url_datefmt(date1))
    date_tm_obj_usr = datetime.strptime(date2, '%b %d %Y %I:%M %p')
    return (date_tm_obj_url > date_tm_obj_usr)
```

The `compare_date` is intended to compare 2 datetime objects (dates) and check which is more current than the other. One of the dates is got after scraping it out from a webpage and the other is got from the user (when program runs, it asks for the user date)

The date from webpage is in the format `Submitted Jan 15th 2018 11:03 PM by`. But to manage the scenario where the format will vary for cases like `1st`, `2nd`, `3rd`, and `nth`, I have written another function `check_url_datefmt(date1)` which `compare_date` calls:

```
def check_url_datefmt(date):
    print (str(date))
    fmt_lst=['Submitted %b %dst %Y %I:%M %p by','Submitted %b %dnd %Y %I:%M %p by','Submitted %b %drd %Y %I:%M %p by','Submitted %b %dth %Y %I:%M %p by']
    if str(date) == str(fmt_lst[0]):
        return 'Submitted %b %dst %Y %I:%M %p by'
    elif str(date) == str(fmt_lst[1]):
        return 'Submitted %b %dnd %Y %I:%M %p by'
    elif str(date) == str(fmt_lst[2]):
        return 'Submitted %b %drd %Y %I:%M %p by'
    else:
        return 'Submitted %b %dth %Y %I:%M %p by'
```

But I see for all cases, it is matching only the last `else`. In fact for a case `Submitted Jan 3rd 2018 11:03 PM by` it returns `'Submitted %b %dth %Y %I:%M %p by'`, and as a result I get this error:

```
File "C:\python-scripts\url_scraper1.py", line 65, in compare_date
date_tm_obj_url = datetime.strptime(date1, check_url_datefmt(date1))
  File "C:\Users\SIDDHARTHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "C:\Users\SIDDHARTHA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
(data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Submitted Jan 3rd 2018 11:03 PM by' does not match format 'Submitted %b %dth %Y %I:%M %p by'
```

What am I doing wrong? How to get over this?

Comment: How about just removing `st`, `nd`, `rd`and `th` from the string before parsing? Then you can use one single template for all your strings.

Comment: You're comparing `Submitted Jan 3rd 2018 11:03 PM by` to `Submitted %b %dst %Y %I:%M %p by`, so of course they aren't equal and you always fall into the `else`.

Comment: @All Thanks for clearing up the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`check_url_datefmt(date)` doesn't work as you expect because `date` is an actual date string and therefore doesn't match any of the date format strings you're trying. In other words, the string `Submitted Jan 3rd 2018 11:03 PM by` doesn't match any of the strings in `fmt_lst`.

The simplest solution is to just call `datetime.strptime()` with all the formats until one of them matches.